# Pass function to an Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to pass a function to a component? I'm trying to move my code away from views and towards components to keep my Ember app moving forward (see [here](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/preparing-for-ember-2.0/)), and I've got a bunch of commonly used functions I use throughout my site. I am not sure how to call them from within a component. I had put them in their own controller in my older code, but I hear it's sloppy or unwise to pass controllers to a component.

For example in a component handlebars file, I'm considering this:

```
{{a-cool-component 
  property1=someValue
  function1=controllers.utils.doSomethingRepetitious 
}}
```

So that in my component javascript code I can do something like this...

```
FacetListItemComponent = Ember['default'].Component.extend({
  property1: null
  property2: null
  function1: null 
  didInsertElement: function() {
    //... do stuff here
    this.set('property2', this.function1(this.get('property1')));
  }
);
exports['default'] = FacetListItemComponent;
```

I tried it in a component I'm building, but the `function1` came across as *undefined*.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Ember 1.11 on Ember-CLI 0.2.7

Bryan

Comment: This is a massive code smell. What is this function that you want to pass in doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using get(), and you don't need to set `function1: null` on the component.

```
//component
MyExComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var fun = this.get('function1');
    fun()
  }
})

//other component

MyOtherComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  function1: function(){
    alert('hello');
  }
})

//other component template

{{my-ex
  function1=function1}}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. It will certainly keep me from the "code smell" of passing controllers and enables me to reuse code efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: It's good to point out that doing it this way, the function will be executed in the scope of the window, and not the parent object.  AKA your `this` will be the window.

Comment: you could use a computed property, that would return the function.

example: 

`function1: Ember.computed(function() {
  return Ember.run.bind(this, this._function1)
})
`

this would preserve the context of this

Comment: could you clarify if this works between Route.extend and components? I want to use components in my routes and define a call back for the route then execute the callback inside the component. I am getting the same error with this example using it between routes and components.